# Is there a UI for realm, to view the contents put in the DB?

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to see the contents I put in the realm db. Is there any UI I can use for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called Realm Browser and you can download it through the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12)

Comment: Thanks much, David.